# How do I bulk delete documents in Cloudant-Node-SDK?

Tags: ibm-cloud, couchdb, cloudant

I am using the [Cloudant-Node-SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ibm-cloud/cloudant) and I want to bulk delete some documents. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The `postBulkDocs` function allows to insert, update or delete multiple documents with one call.

To delete, call it with a `_deleted` flag in each document.

For example, if you have these three docs (you only need their `_id` and `_rev` to delete):

```
var docs = [{
  _id: '0007241142412418284',
  _rev: '2-4567766',
  _deleted: true
},
{
  _id: '000459458904590453',
  _rev: '3-59695945',
  _deleted: true
},
{
  _id: '0004590650650678',
  _rev: '2-796865867967',
  _deleted: true
}]
```

..then as long as they each have a `_deleted:true` flag in the body, then they will be deleted when you call the postBulkDocs function:

```
await service.postBulkDocs({
  db: 'mydb',
  bulkDocs: {"docs":docs}
})
```

There are more examples in the [API documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cloudant?code=node#postbulkdocs).